# Thinking Sphinx Sort Order doesn't work as expected.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have a column in the join(middle) table. I want to search on that column that is position

here is my index file

```
 ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :restaurant, :with => :active_record, :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do

   indexes schools.school_name, :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
   indexes schools.branch_name, :sortable => true, :as => :branch_name
   indexes contact_info.restaurant_name, :sortable => true, :as => :restaurant_name
   indexes delivery_info.delivery_charges, :as => :delivery_charges

   indexes restaurant_schools.position, :as => :restaurant_position, :sortable => true

   has restaurant_info.is_pick_up, :as => :pick_up, :facet => true
   has delivery_info.is_delivery,  :as => :delivery, :facet => true
   has schools.id, :as => :school_id, :facet => true

   has restaurant_categories.id, :as => :restaurant_category_ids, :facet => true
   has restaurant_info.min_order, :as => :min_order, :type => :float

   has avg_rating, :as => :rating, :type => :integer
   has ranking, :as => :ranking, :type => :integer

   has delivery_info.delivery_estimated_time, :as => :delivery_eta, :type => :integer

   set_property :min_infix_len => 1
 end
```

When i do query like:

```
 @restaurants = Restaurant.search :with => {:school_id =>  school_ids }
 @restaurants = @restaurants.search :order => :restaurant_position
```

Its not giving me records as it should be.

Please advice what should i fix the get the accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note here.

Firstly: your `restaurant_position` field is a collection of many values (if `restaurant_schools` is a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, which the plural name suggests). This means it actually ends up being a string of values concatenated together (with space characters as the separator). e.g. "1 4 7 2"

Secondly: even if you changed it to an attribute, it would be a multi-value attribute. Sorting against a multi-value attribute doesn't make sense (should the average of all values be used? The smallest? The largest? The sum?).

And finally: Perhaps you're hoping the filter you're providing (on `school_id`) to link into the sorting logic? Sphinx is not a relational database, nor does it have any concept of hashes/dictionaries, so there's no connection between each restaurant_position value and the corresponding school they may be associated with in your database.

If you *do* want that connection, then it's best to have a Sphinx index on the model which has one school and one position (I'm guessing that's `RestaurantSchool`). From there, you can pull in relevant fields and attributes via associations, but you can also search/sort with something like this:

```
RestaurantSchool.search :with => {:school_id => school_ids}, :order => :position
```

Comment: I have has_many through association, between schools and restaurants. I want to search if a school name is given I need to fetch their restaurants ordered by position(Middle table field)

Comment: Right, so my suggestion to search on RestaurantSchool sounds like the right approach.